# How to use visitLdcInsn to load Object

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am using ASM to inject code and have been lucky so far with it ,during a stress test i observed that i see some performance degradation as the code i wrote is making lot of static calls , to optimize it i tried to cache the variable which i use.In the original code this is what i did

```
  visitor.visitLdcInsn(getMethodName());
  visitor.visitLdcInsn(getDescriptor());
  visitor.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, MYTRACKER.HELPER_CLASS,     
          MYTrackingConstants.HELPER_GET_CLIENT_METHOD,MYTrackingConstants.HELPER_GET_CLIENT_METHOD_DESC);
.
.
```

The above static call is causing performance issues as it is called number of time,to optimize it i cached the object and added a gettermethod in the same class and tried to use it,the above code now is replaced by below one

```
visitor.visitLdcInsn(getRTTDescriptor());
```

but when i run, i get this exception

```
      [err] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value com.vish.MyTransformDescriptor@63f463f4
      [err]     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.a(Unknown Source)
      [err]     at [internal classes]
      [err]     at  sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:181)
      [err]     at  sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:377)
      [err]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method) 
      [err]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
```

After reading javadoc for visitLdcInsn i realized that we cant just directly use anything of type Object(getDescriptor returns Object where as getMethodName and getDescriptor returns string) unless it is of org.objectweb.asm.Type can you any one help me or provide a sample example of how can i use Type to load my object??

Below is a snippet of my code

```
public RTMethodAdapter{
Object rttd;
public RTMethodAdapter(MethodVisitor visitor, MethodInfo mInfo, String reqOpsType, String classname,Object rttd, AnalyzerAdapter aa)
{
 . 
 .
 .
 this.rttd = rttd;
}

public Object getRTTDescriptor(){
    return rttd;
}
public String getMethodName() {
    return methodInfo.getMethodName();
}

public String getDescriptor() {
    return methodInfo.getDescriptor();
}
}
```

Thanks

VishwanathB

Answer (score 1):

Ldc stands for load constant. You can only use it for constants that are known when (re)writing the class.

Furthermore, it can only be used for specific types of constants: ints, longs, floats, doubles, strings, classes, methodhandles and methodtypes. And the constant strings are limited to 64kb.

Lastly, this probably won't make a difference, since the JVM should optimize away things like this anyway if the value truly is a constant. Have you profiled to determine that this is actually a problem?

Comment: Thanks Antimony,I saw this javadoc from ASM 4.0 and i see this for visitLdcInsn
"
 } else if (cst instanceof Type) {
   int sort = ((Type) cst).getSort();
   if (sort == Type.OBJECT) {
     // ...
   }
 } else if (cst instanceof Handle) {
   // ...
 } else {
   // throw an exception
 }
cst - the constant to be loaded on the stack. This parameter must be a non null Integer, a Float, a Long, a Double, a String, a Type of OBJECT or ARRAY sort for .class constants,
"
reading this i thought there may be a way to load object as well..